# Facebook share link: &display=popup not popping up

Tags: facebook, popup

Hey I'd like to have it so that the Facebook share link pops up rather than opens to a new page. I'm just going from their example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

and I figured that "$display=popup" would imply that it well, displays a popup. I'm new to working with Facebook sharing, and I'm finding a million solutions on how to *not* have it popup. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display just control the look. You still need to pop the popup your self

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't sure if that was the case or not, thanks for confirming.